# Remove check all button from table in UI5

Tags: sapui5

I have a grid table (`sap.ui.table.Table`) in my application. Each row has check box and there is also option as "Select All" in header of the table.

I want to remove the "Select All"-CheckBox and keep functionality of checking single/multiple rows at each row level. Is this possible?

Please see this link: https://jsbin.com/vizozutubi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide "Select All"-CheckBox from Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51324035/how-to-hide-select-all-checkbox-from-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There is a way to hide that multi select checkbox

```
oTable.setEnableSelectAll(false);
```