# How to hide "Select All"-CheckBox from Table?

Tags: sapui5

I want to remove the check box which enables selecting all items from the table (`sap.m.Table`).

I tried:

```js
var oTable = this.byId('MyTableId');
oTable._getSelectAllCheckbox().setVisible(false);
```

It didn't work for me. Is there a way to set it false **in XML**?
I know I can use CSS but I want to use CSS only if there is no other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## sap.m.Table

<sup>(aka. *Responsive Table*)</sup>

Currently, there is no publicly documented API to enable/disable showing the "Select All"-CheckBox on `sap.m.Table`. Best practice in this case is to extend the control and to switch the `bPreventMassSelection` state accordingly.

Here is a snippet from the **sample: [https://embed.plnkr.co/pnpdRK7d7CxZXZ8s](https://embed.plnkr.co/pnpdRK7d7CxZXZ8s?show=view/App.view.xml,preview)**

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/m/Table",
  "sap/m/TableRenderer",
], function(Table, TableRenderer) {
  "use strict";

  return Table.extend("demo.control.MyResponsiveTable", {
    metadata: {
      properties: {
        showSelectAll: {
          type: "boolean",
          bindable: true,
        },
      },
    },

    setShowSelectAll: function(bValue) {
      this.bPreventMassSelection = !bValue;
      this.setProperty("showSelectAll", bValue);
      return this;
    },

    renderer: TableRenderer,
  });
});
```

```xml
<demo:MyResponsiveTable xmlns:demo="demo.control"
  showSelectAll="{/showSelectAll}"
  mode="MultiSelect">
```

Compared to `_getSelectAllCheckbox`, the above approach should be favored since:

- `_getSelectAllCheckbox` is a **private method**.

  - Private methods are not intended to be used outside of the control definition.
  - Relying on private methods and/or manipulating the internal control (`CheckBox`) **will** break the app in future UI5 releases.
- The `bPreventMassSelection` on the other hand is a simple flag which is already used widely in other controls that rely on `sap.m.Table`/`.List` internally. We can see that Table skips rendering the "Select All"-CheckBox if `bPreventMassSelection` is enabled.

---

## sap.ui.table.Table

<sup>(aka. *Grid Table*)</sup>

In case someone was looking for the solution but with `sap.ui.table.Table`, set the [`enableSelectAll`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.table.Table#methods/setEnableSelectAll) property to `false`:

```xml
<table:Table xmlns:table="sap.ui.table"
  enableSelectAll="false"
  selectionMode="MultiToggle">
```

Answer (score -1):

`oTable._getSelectAllCheckbox().setVisible(false);` worked as expected for me.
I've added it as follows:

```js
this._myDelegate = {
    onAfterRendering: function () {
        if (typeof this._getSelectAllCheckbox === "function" && this._getSelectAllCheckbox().isA("sap.m.CheckBox")) {
            this._getSelectAllCheckbox().setVisible(false);
        }
    }
};
oTable.addEventDelegate(this._myDelegate, oTable);
// Remove this._myDelegate from the table in `onExit` to avoid memory leak
```

Make sure you have the right table control on `var oTable = this.byId("MyTableId");`.